# jQuery .ajax jsonp request to URL with an unnamed parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to make a jsonp request using $.ajax() to a URL that takes the form:

`http://realtimedata.water.nsw.gov.au/cgi/webservice.server.pl?jsoncallback=printData&{"function":"get_ts_traces","version":1,"params":{}}`

Notice that the object after the & in the URL doesn't have a parameter name

I've tried the following which gets a response, but the data object doesn't get passed correctly resulting in an error response from the API:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "http://realtimedata.water.nsw.gov.au/cgi/webservice.server.pl",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "jsoncallback",
  jsonpCallback: "parseData",
  data: {" ": {"function":"get_ts_traces","version":1,"params":{}}},
});
```

The question is how do I correctly make a request using $.ajax() to this URL?

I've successfully used string concatenation and appending a script tag to the DOM for the jsonp request, but I'd like to use this jQuery method. Cheers.

Comment: Why does it have to be unnamed?

Comment: That's the form the URL has to be in for the API

Answer (score 0):

It should be a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me to, yet.

I would recommend to send that json stringified:

```
data: JSON.stringify( {" ": {"function":"get_ts_traces","version":1,"params":{}}} ),
```

Regards!

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. The main issue is the URL structure though.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I'm looking for. Thx.

`var data = {
      function: "get_ts_traces",
      version: 1,
      params: {}
    };`

`$.ajax('http://realtimedata.water.nsw.gov.au/cgi/webservice.server.pl', {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});`